# Error Number: 1064 (DELET with sql JOIN)

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I want delete ROW(s) in two database table(mysql) with sql JOIN but get error:

This is my sql code:

> **table_1.id** => have one row with id `3`
>   **table_2.rela** => have three row with real `3` (sometimes number row table_2.rela join with table_1.id is 1 or 5 or 2 or ...)

```
  //$id = $this->input->post('id');
    $id = '3';
        $this->db->query("
        DELETE *
        FROM table_1
        JOIN  table_2
           ON table_1.id = table_2.rela
        WHERE table_1.id = '.$id.'");
```

With above query i get this error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>  Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '* FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_1.' at line 1
>
> DELETE * FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.rela WHERE
>   table_1.id = '.3.'

How is fix it?

Comment: look at my answer and you'll see why htere is no deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the wildcard after the `DELETE`. You have to specify the table from which you want to delete records. Your query should be something like:

```
$this->db->query("
        DELETE table_1, table_2
        FROM table_1
        JOIN  table_2
           ON table_1.id = table_2.rela
        WHERE table_1.id = ".floor($id));
```

Assuming that the ids are int. This also removes invalid characters if the $id may come from user input.

Comment: Op wants to delete rows in both tables

Comment: I edited my answer. I added the other table too. After the `DELETE` you just have to specify all tables you want to delete from.

Comment: still a problem with the sql string

Comment: read my answer I explain it there

Comment: Don't work for delete row(s). what do i do?

Comment: @Mehdi Seif, run the edited version, you were not escaping the $id properly...

Comment: If want add several table for delete in this sql, how is it?

Comment: Please see my post and tell me about it?

Answer (score 0):

You should mention at least one table name before the `FROM` clause, from which you wants to delete the matching rows . If you want to delete the matching rows from both tables, mention both of the tables separated by comma.

```
$this->db->query("
        DELETE table_1
        FROM table_1
        JOIN  table_2
           ON table_1.id = table_2.rela
        WHERE table_1.id = '".$id."'");
```

Comment: He wants to delete rows in both tables

Comment: @LaurenceBurke: He can put both the table names separated by comma

Comment: still his problems are more than that his sql string is off

Comment: Your code don't have error and don't done deletion. why?

Comment: @Mehdi: Because you are binding the PHP variable `$id ` wrongly. Check the updated query

Comment: If want add several table for delete in this sql, how is it?

Comment: @MehdiSeif: I suggest, You should read about it once http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Please see my update in post and tell me about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = '3';
    $this->db->query("
    DELETE table_1, table_2
    FROM table_1
    JOIN  table_2
       ON table_1.id = table_2.rela
    WHERE table_1.id = $id");
```

Also in your original question you are using the string wrong you $id is wrapped by double quotes and you use single to try and concatenate... since its in double quotes and your $id is most likely a number you don't need to wrap it in single quotes for the sql... all you would need is `"table_1.id = $id";`

Comment: If want add several table for delete in this sql, how is it?

Comment: OK it the end he'll be left with a possible injection, cause this `$id = '3';` couldn't be anything but a test. Just being thorough :)

Comment: @Nikoloff It deosnt matter the OP is having a hard time understanding what were even trying to explain to him with the simple fixes to his answer I think that sql injection checks would be to hard to explain with the language barrier for him

Comment: Agreed, I already regret opening this question at all...